# I cant get $_POST from js to php in wordpress with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

My js file is here.

```
      function sayHelloWorld() {
window.alert('hey');
       $.ajax({
         url: 'admin-ajax.php',//I wrote absolute path here.
         type:'POST',
         data: { 
                'action': "mon_action",
                'newFormRecherche': 'newFormRecherche'
            },
        timeout:10000,
        }).done(function(data) {
            window.alert(data);
        }).fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            window.alert("error");
      });
```

and functions.php is here.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_mon_action', 'mon_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mon_action', 'mon_action' );

function mon_action() {

    if (isset($_POST["newFormRecherche"])) {
      $field1='hey';
        exit();
    }else{
      $field1='heye';
        exit();
    }
    echo 'echo';
    die();
}
```

this process succeeds and I get window.alert(data), but data is empty. could you tell me why this does not include 'echo'?
(this script is something that I am just trying.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to echo some data on php function like this

```
if (isset($_POST["newFormRecherche"])) {
      $field1='hey';
      echo 'if';
        exit();
    }else{
      $field1='heye';
echo 'else';
        exit();
    }
    echo 'echo';
    die();
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is echoing and the page comes out empty becuase you're exiting before `echo 'echo';`, your code should be

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_mon_action', 'mon_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mon_action', 'mon_action' );

function mon_action() {

    if (isset($_POST["newFormRecherche"])) {
      $field1='hey';
    }else{
      $field1='heye';
    }
    echo 'echo';
    die();
}
```